# Horizontal scroll view hiding some children

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Android 4.1.0.

I have one horizontal scroll view, inside it - `LinearLayout`.
In LinearLayout I add some children programmatically in fragment `onResume`.
In the case when children fit in the view, everything is fine.
In the case when children do not fit in the view, `HorizontalView` hides first **n** elements from the left and keep free space for n elements on the right.

I tried to call `computeScroll` or `requestLayout`/`forceLayout`, but it didn't help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/productListScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/productListLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code in fragment:

```
    public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         productsPanel.removeAllViews();
         for (Product product : currentOrder.getProductList()) {
             productsPanel.addView(new ...); //view with calculated height and width
             productsPanel.addView(new ...); //view with fixed width and height = MATCH_PARENT
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!-- Lots of items -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

It was issue. Horizontal scroll view hides its children if you set `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for inner container.
link is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20088)

Comment: Thanks. I wasted time until find this answer.

Comment: Works perfectly ...but not understanding  why `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"' required

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasted time until find this answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by setting linear layout `layout_gravity=left`, `gravity=center`.
I also moved view creation code to `onActivityCreated`, but I don't think it helped to solve this problem.